How does Python *actually* decide on the order when making a list from a set in Python 3.9+
I was curious about this, because knowing the answer will possibly help in bugtesting a Python project of mine that uses sets, and sometimes converts them to lists. I am not sure how it works, because the outcome of the code described below does not match anything I could find online.
The weird effect I am having is that the output of the program below depends on the value of Orange. I wonder if other users get the same, but I get the commented output below depending on the value of Orange. I get the same output 100% of the time. Does anyone know what happens here, and/or how to get consistent output that would not depend on the value of Orange (because I would like to insert debugging code in the place of Orange and not have the output change)
import numpy as np

class Banana(object):
    def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = label

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Banana(label={})'.format(self.label)

class Apple(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._bananas = {1:set()}

    def add_banana(self, banana: "Banana"):
        self._bananas[1].add(banana)

    @property
    def print_bananas(self) -> list["Banana"]:
        result = set()
        for banana in self._bananas.values():
            result |= banana
        return list(result)

Lemon = 11
for i in range(10):
    Orange = 4
    A = Apple()
    B1 = Banana(1)
    B2 = Banana(2)
    B3 = Banana(3)
    A.add_banana(B1)
    A.add_banana(B2)
    A.add_banana(B3)
    print(A.print_bananas[0].label)

#result with Orange = 5: 3,3,2,1,2,3,3,2,1,2
#result with Orange = 4: 3,3,3,1,2,3,3,3,1,2

I am aware that debugging is not a very good idea if you want to test for bug that only show up sometimes (I am using quite some randomization, although for most of the random elements, like np.random, I can just fix the seed). But I hope, from seeing that the outcome can somewhat be fixed, that there is a way to completely fix it. For what I could find online, it depends on the environment variable PYHTONHASHSEED (for example here). I tried setting PYTHONHASHSEED to 0 in the environment variables in PyCharm, and restarting Python multiple times, but this had no effect on the output. I read somewhere that PYTHONHASHSEED would be disabled after Python 3.8 but don't remember where I read it. I am using Python 3.10 and Pycharm Community Edition 2021.3.2
Remark: it was quite difficult to reproduce the behaviour, it only seems to occur for specific values of Lemon and/or Orange, and possibly depends on your system if and when it appears. For me, the strange behaviour shows up both in Windows 11 and in Linux Mint (with slightly different output). The output seemed always random in Anaconda, and for one of the reviewers it was always the same for Darwin.

The order is an internal implementation detail. You should not try to write code that relies on any such implementation details. It’s fragile madness. Why it behaves exactly like this in this case is something something memory layout hand wavey something something optimisation happenstance. Again, even if we would figure it out in excruciating detail, it’s not any sort of information you should be using for anything practical.
